# AJAX Code get random image not work in Firefox, IE, Edge (only Chrome works)

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX to show random images.
following code is good for text, but not good for images till now.
(problem is : I cannot get random images after click 'Change')

here is the code:

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax(url,tag) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xxx = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xxx = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }

  xxx.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xxx.readyState == 4 && xxx.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML = xxx.responseText;
    }
  }

  xxx.open('GET', url, true);
  xxx.send();
}
</script>

<div id="code"><img src="generate.php"></div><br>
<input type="submit" value="Change" onclick="ajax('code.php','code');">
```

code.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$_SESSION['text'] = rand(1000,9999);
?>
<img src="generate.php">
```

generate.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

if (!isset($_SESSION['text'])) {
  $_SESSION['text'] = rand(1000,9999);
}

$text = $_SESSION['text'];

$im = imagecreate(50, 20);
imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $text, $textcolor);
imagejpeg($im);
?>
```

I have no idea how to fix it, please help, thanks.

Comment: Does it work at the first load of page ? It should be

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check browser console

Comment: updated: problem is : I cannot get random images after click 'Change' using firefox etc.

Comment: your code won't work like this IMO - the ajax callback is trying to process `responseText` but the `code.php` attempts to create an html `img` element- which is not text

Comment: I see, need some encode maybe, I will try to find more info about it. thanks.